# Option for tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I heard that TF 2.0 will remove tf.contrib, what is the best alternative for `tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor` function in TF 1.12?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: tf.contrib deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344172/tensorflow-tf-contrib-deprecation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much of the functionality in `tf.contrib.lookup` has been migrated to [`tf.lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/lookup), though I do not believe there is a 1:1 mapping for `tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor`. To date, the available endpoints are:

- `KeyValueTensorInitializer` - table initializers given `keys` and `values` tensors.
- `StaticHashTable` - a generic hash table implementation.
- `StaticVocabularyTable` - string to ID table wrapper that assigns out-of-vocabulary keys to buckets.
- `TextFileInitializer` - table initializers from a text file.
- `experimental.DenseHashTable` - generic mutable hash table implementation using tensors as the backing store.

You can find out more about `tf.contrib` deprecation and functionality migration in the [Sunsetting `tf.contrib` RFC](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md).